# Getx Controllers null values at first

Tags: flutter, firebase, model-view-controller, controller, flutter-getx

i am working on flutter project Apply Getx and MVC Arcitecture but when i am getting stream from firestore first it got null values but when hot reload on that page values will goes in to place how to remove this Error, Almost in All type of modules I have to face this Error.

I am trying init State but Ui build first than function in Init State.

Comment: you should add code snippets of what you tried

Answer (score 1):

It is quite normal for `StreamBuilder`s or `FutureBuilder`s to call their builder function with `null` values.

The reason is that the `build` function may be called at any time, irrespective of the stream or future's state.

You should use the `hasData` property of the snapshot to check for valid data, and handle the case of `null` data, e.g. by returning a `SizedBox` widget.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: yourStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
       return yourWidget();
    } else {
       return const SizedBox();
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: can you please provide me the code for better Understanding

Comment: @SamiUllah I have added some sample code to my answer.